# Fiat Punto Grande 2008 Immobiliser light on and car does not crank

Tags: electrical, fiat

FIAT Punto Grande 2008. My daughter was driving her Punto and the immobiliser light came on. Nothing happened to the car, she drove the short distance home and turned the car off. The car has not started since and the immobiliser light is on. I towed the car home and paid a company to diagnose the problem. The chap told me that the issue was the EPS (electronic power steering) a common fault with Punto's. I got a replacement (reconditioned) EPS and fitted it my self. I then tried to start the car and the immobiliser warning light is still on. Could the issue have been with the ECU rather than the EPS?. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the check engine light?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the immobilizer light is on, that would indicate to me the ignition isn't registering the key or there's an issue with the BCM or whatever is controlling the security module in the vehicle. The reason it would drive with the light on at first is because the car was already running, then once the ignition was shut off, it could no longer get started again because the security wouldn't allow it. I really have no clue what EPS would have to do with any of this?

Comment: Could the ECU be at fault, would a faulty ECU allow the car to run for 10 miles or so without impairing the running of the car? What does the Body Computer do exactly and could this failure be my issue?